# Expected value of prize winners

Tags: probability, expectation

Consider a group consisting of $w$ women, $c$ children and $r$ rabbits. Assume that no two individuals
have same height. Moreover, each rabbit is shorter in height than each child, who in turn is shorter
than each women. Consider two types of games. Each game starts with a set of participants
arranged in a line from left to right in a uniformly random order. There is a pile of prizes at the left
end of the line. Assume that a participant at place $i$ would see the prize if none of the participants
preceding him/her is taller than him/her.

(a) **Game A** : all rabbits, women and children participate in the game. What would be the
expected number of children who can see the prize.

(b) **Game B** : all rabbits, women and children participate in the game. A woman can receive
the prize only if she can see the prize and there is at least one child preceding her in the line.
What is the expected number of women that would win the prize ?

**My try** I think I should find the probability for a child of a given height to see prize, then sum it for all children, which would give total expected value by linearity of expectation, but I can't find a closed expression. I am also not sure if it's correct.

Comment: It seems as though we can ignore the rabbits, can we not?

Comment: in general, the expected number of children who will see the prize is $\sum{n_i p_{n_i}}$ where $n_i\le3$ and $i$ is the ith permutation of women and children ordering

Comment: $p_0$ = probability that all of the women are to the left of all the children

Comment: The are $w!$ permutations for $n=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution on Game A.**

It is evident that the rabbits play no part in this.

Let's number the human participants as $P_1,\dots,P_{c+w}$ and $P_i$ has larger length than $P_{i+1}$ for $i=1,\dots,c+w-1$. So $P_1,\dots, P_w$ are women and $P_{w+1},\dots,P_{c+w}$ are children.

Further let $B_i\sim\mathsf{Bern}(p_i)$ taking value $1$ if $P_i$ sees the price.

The probability that person $P_1$ sees the price is $p_1=1$. Further $P_{2}$ will see it if she is on the correct side of $P_1$, so this event has probability $p_2=\frac12$. The probability that $P_{3}$ sees the price is $p_3=\frac13$ (i.e. the probability that she is the utmost left (if I understand well, else right) of $P_1,P_{2}$ and $P_{3}$) et cetera.

That gives expectation: $$\mathsf E(B_{c+w}+\dots+B_{1+w})=\sum_{i=1+w}^{c+w}\frac1{i}$$ for the number of children that see the price.

--

**Solution on Game B.**

Here we work with $C_i\sim\mathsf{Bern}(q_i)$ for $i=1,\dots,w$ where $q_i$ denotes the probability that woman $P_i$ can receive the price. Here we have:$$q_i=1-\left[\frac{i-1}{i}+\frac1{c+i}\right]=\frac1{i}-\frac1{c+i}$$

This because $\frac{i-1}i=1-\frac{1}{i}$ denotes the probability that woman $i$ will not stand on the right place when it concerns the women (a taller woman keeps the price out of her sight) and $\frac1{c+i}$ is the probability that she will stand on the right place when it concerns the women but all children are standing on the side of the taller women as well, so that no child is between her and the price, as is requested. This involves the location of $c+i$ persons.

So then we end up with:$$\mathsf E(C_1+\cdots+C_w)=\sum_{i=1}^w\left[\frac1i-\frac1{c+i}\right]$$

Comment: And for the second game, should we have tallest woman is to the right of first child from left in the queue(p=1/2), second tallest to the left of tallest and to the right of leftmost child(p=1/6), then for next case p=1/12, then 1/20, 1/42, ... ??

Comment: I don't really understand. In my conception: for the second game a new sequence of Bernouilli($q_i$) where $q_1$ is the probability that the tallest woman has at least one child on the correct side (so $q_1=1-\frac{1}{1+c}$ where $\frac1{1+c}$ is the probability that no children are between her and the price). This however grows difficult for $i>1$ because then the condition that $P_i$ can see the price has influence on the number of children she will have on her side. I have no solution for B yet.

Comment: Thanks for the brilliant insight into this question

Comment: You are very welcome.